# How to set path for sudo commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, path, sudo

If I issue

```
sudo my-command
```

how does Linux look for that `my-command`?

The `my-command` is in my PATH. I can invoke it without any problem. However, when I invoke it with `sudo`, I'll get `command not found`.
How to overcome it?

**EDIT:** That *"Possible duplicate"*'s selected answer is wrong, well, at least not to the point. This answer, from terdon, is the correct one.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This is normally set by the `secure_path` option in `/etc/sudoers`. From `man sudoers`:

```
 secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't
               trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environ‐
               ment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if
               you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user
               path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group
               option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not
               set by default.
```

To run commands that are not in the default `$PATH`, you can either

1. Use the full path: `sudo ~/bin/my-command`; or
2. Add the directory containing the command to `secure_path`. Run `sudo visudo` and edit the secure path line:

   ```
   Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/youruser/bin/"
   ```

   Save the file and next time you run `sudo`, the directory `~/bin` will be in its `$PATH`.

Comment: Or just comment out the whole line if this isn't a production machine and we don't care. Then it will use the users' PATH. It says that it's not set by default, but that may not always be true...

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `sudo env PATH=$PATH ...rest_of_command_here...`. Since that's not so convenient to type, I've added an alias `alias sudop='sudo env PATH=$PATH'`. The `sudop` (rather than aliasing `sudo` itself) is a reminder to me to make me aware that I am preserving my current environment path.

Comment: This is a good method. Note, you can simply omit `env` here, and then the PATH variable is set as usual for any other simple shell command.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I used for a workaround:

```
sudo cp $(which my-command) /usr/bin
...
```

The `which` command is executed in a subshell that is non-root, so it is able to find `my-command`, then, sudo copies the executable to a path that the `root` user can access. Not great for security, but it was ok for me running a docker image that was being destroyed right after the command was run.

Comment: I prefer this answer. It also worked like charm, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### How to symlink or copy an executable to a bin dir that `sudo` has access to

I'm using a text editor called `micro`. I ran `sudo micro /etc/sysctl.conf` and got this error:

```
sudo: micro: command not found
```

That's because `micro` is in my `~/bin` dir, but that's a personal bin dir to my user only. To give `sudo` access to it, I can either symlink it or copy it to `/usr/bin` as well:

```bash
# symlink it (my preference)
# Create a symlink at /usr/bin/micro which points to my personal ~/bin/micro
# executable
sudo ln -si ~/bin/micro /usr/bin

# OR: copy it
sudo cp -i ~/bin/micro /usr/bin
```

Done. Now when I run `sudo micro` it works fine.