# "Command not found" while using sudo with nano

Tags: linux, sudo, nano

I got a problem when I want to edit files using `nano` with `sudo`.
When I enter the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/exports
```

I got this error

> ```
> sudo: nano: command not found
> ```

This is the return from `echo $PATH`:

```
/home/einzelkind/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

I installed `nano` like this:

1. Download the package with `wget https://nano-editor.org/dist/`
2. extract the files with `tar -xvJf`
3. `./configure --enable-utf8 --enable-nanorc`
4. `sudo make`
5. `sudo make install`

Nano is installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`? Anyway,

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/nano
```

should always work, no matter how `$PATH` is configured.

Comment: `sudo /usr/local/bin/nano` works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of `echo $PATH` try `sudo echo $PATH`
Seems root it uses a different one from the user:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path

Also, installing packages via package managers is, or so I heard multiple times, a better solution than building manually. Not only because of the ease of uninstallation!
Depending on your system it might be: `apt-get`, `yum` or `pacman`.

Comment: Your link is useful but the command `sudo echo $PATH` is not. The shell expands `$PATH` first, then `sudo` gets its *value*.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. Thanks @KamilMaciorowski.  
So I guess the way to find the PATH for root would be to `su` first and then `echo $PATH`, hm?  
Anyway, as @jvb suggested - running with absolute path will suffice.